# Compile Ubuntu Touch no rules to make target "APPS/../src/R.stamp"

Tags: java, android, compilation, r.java-file, ubuntu-touch

I'm trying to compile Ubuntu Touch for Galaxy Note 10.1, and I'm stucked on this error while compiling:

```
make: ***  Aucune règle pour fabriquer la cible « /home/vincent/Documents/DEV/ubuntutouch/out/target/common/obj/APPS/framework-res_intermediates/src/R.stamp », nécessaire pour « /home/vincent/Documents/DEV/ubuntutouch/out/target/common/obj/APPS/AdvancedDisplay_intermediates/src/R.stamp ». Arrêt.
```

What I've done is :

1. Download Ubuntu Touch Source with "phablet-dev-bootstrap"
2. Getting specific files for this Samsung device
3. ". build/envsetup.sh" and "lunch"
4. "make"

Has someone a clue?

Comment: After trying many things, it seems that the application "AdvancedDisplay" , who is located in "hardware/samsung/" isn't able to be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I progressed, I finally understood what the message means.

The makefiles try to compile the application "AdvancedDisplay.apk", which depends from the application "framework-res.apk". But the R.stamp, which is needed, has not been compiled.

I could test directly the errors that were produced with the command "mmm frameworks/base/core/res/" which compile the makefile of the subdirectory, without wait for other works of compilation.
For this solution to work, you must have let "make -j1" work (and again and again) until the target "aapt" has been built.

The error was due to "add-resource" missing in some res/config.xml files, that I had to modify... to get other errors !!!

As I didn't get the last Ubuntu Touch version (phablet-dev-bootstrap gets the 4.4.2 version by default), I will try the last branch, and will leave these errors behind me for now.

Comment: Same problem on the branch 6.0.0_r1.